# My jQuery is noticeably slower than native JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've rewritten my menu handling with jquery and all of a sudden all my menus appear to take significantly longer to open. With native JS the opening slide animation was played instantly after pressing the trigger, with jQ it takes a full second before the menu opens. I've since moved all the code back to native, but this is the basic function that I used for the opening.

jQuery version:

```
$("#apis_trigger").click(function() {

    $("#apis_menu").switchClass(dstart, dend);
    $("#apis_trigger .down_arrow").css("transform", "scaleY(-1)");

});
```

Native JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("apis_trigger").onclick = function() {

    document.getElementById("apis_menu").classList.remove(dstart);
    document.getElementById("apis_menu").classList.add(dend);

    document.querySelector("#apis_trigger .down_arrow").style.transform="scaleY(-1)";
}
```

I'm just querying the selectors and switching classes, so I didn't expect this kind of a performance hit.

I knew about the performance penalty after reading this thread

> This is the amount of code jquery goes through when we use a simple $('selector')
>
> http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=init

But from reading other threads I thought that would only be apparent in larger scripts.

Just for reference I'm running this in Chrome on i7 2.3ghz w/9gb ram.

Comment: It should be very fast in jquery too it's a bug. Can you try the lastest jquery 3 ? Your tranform is not the same in the jquery version ( -1 instead or 1 ?)

Comment: To be fair, `.switchClass()` is a jQuery UI function, so you've included more than just plain jQuery. Not that I think that should be such a major performance difference though. What was your question btw?

Comment: You should make a fiddle for this so we can see what's going on.

Comment: `switchClass` does animation of all properties for 400 ms by default. You should use `$("#apis_menu").removeClass(dstart).addClass(dend)` to make "fair" comparison.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko yes that's it, the delay disappeared. Thanks, you should add this as an answer.

Comment: you should provide a demo page. what you are saying is absolutely impossible and absurd

Answer (score 1):

> switchClass does animation of all properties for 400 ms by default. You should use $("#apis_menu").removeClass(dstart).addClass(dend) to make "fair" comparison.

– Yury Tarabanko 5 mins ago